# Error al liberar memoria en C++

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en C++ usando memoria dinámica y para esto decidí implementar una pila basada en arreglos.

Hace poco conocí la herramienta valgrind, la cual me avisa si tengo bloques de memoria sin liberar, y a pesar de que el programa corre sin problemas, a la hora de revisarlo con valgrind me aparece el siguiente error:

```
valgrind ./main
==7787== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7787== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL&apos;d, by Julian Seward et al.
==7787== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7787== Command: ./main
==7787== 
==7787== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==7787==    at 0x4C3123B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7787==    by 0x1089BB: Pila::~Pila() (in /home/josue/Escritorio/PIla/Pila basada en arreglos/main)
==7787==    by 0x108B16: main (in /home/josue/Escritorio/PIla/Pila basada en arreglos/main)
==7787==  Address 0x5b7dc80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4,000,000 alloc&apos;d
==7787==    at 0x4C3089F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7787==    by 0x10899B: Pila::Pila() (in /home/josue/Escritorio/PIla/Pila basada en arreglos/main)
==7787==    by 0x108ADF: main (in /home/josue/Escritorio/PIla/Pila basada en arreglos/main)
==7787== 
==7787== 
==7787== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7787==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7787==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 4,072,704 bytes allocated
==7787== 
==7787== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7787== 
==7787== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7787== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Parte del programa es el siguiente:

```
typedef int tElemPila;

class Pila{
  int maxSize;                  
  int stackSize;                
  tElemPila* Array;             

public:
  Pila();
  ~Pila();
  void clear();                 
  int push(tElemPila item);     
  int pop();                    
  tElemPila topValue();         
  int length();                 
  void print();                 
};

Pila::Pila(){
  maxSize = 1000000;
  Array = new tElemPila[maxSize];
  stackSize = 0;
}

Pila::~Pila(){
  delete Array;
}

void Pila::clear(){
  delete Array;
  Array = new tElemPila[maxSize];
  stackSize = 0;
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola. Dado que el new lo haces sobre un array: `Array = new tElementPila[maxSize]`, en el delete lo tienes que indicar así: `delete [] Array`

Comment: @SuperG280 estoy convencido que es la respuesta ¡anímate a responder! :D

Comment: Muy bien formulada esta pregunta. Lo tenía que decir más allá del voto positivo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vale, responderé como dios manda :)

El problema está en la liberación de memoria que haces con el delete. Cuando haces la reserva de memoria así:

```
Array = new tElementPila[ maxSize];
```

estás reservado memoria para maxSize número de elementos del tipo tElementPila, así que en la liberación tienes que indicarle que tiene que eliminar la memoria reservada para todos los elementos, de la forma:

```
delete [] Array;
```

Si no haces eso, y solo haces el delete Array como has hecho tú, el compilador no sabe cuantos elementos hay, con lo que solo eliminaría el primer elemento dejando los demás sin liberar y por eso te avisa de la laguna de memoria.

Cuando ejecutas delete [], el compilador llama al destructor de cada uno de los objetos del array, y después libera la memoria del array de objetos. En tu caso no hay destructor porque los datos son enteros, pero la manera de liberar debe ser la misma.